# Node Request Library Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dns.js 26

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, web-scraping, request

I am scraping a website in a continuous manner (once a day multiple requests) and using the async and request node modules to do so every time. I run the function getPage in parallel using the async eachLimit (not shown in code here). However once in a few thousands queries I get the following error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 247sports.com 247sports.com:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

Even though I know the url I passed it was valid. I found there were solutions for people using the http module and getting the same error but no one seems to be getting this using the request module. 
I know my ip was not blocked as I was able to access the site right after the error. I also know my user-agent is not the problem, as I rotate through a list of user agents, all of which are valid.
My guess is that the problem lies where the request library interacts with the node http module. Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce the problem accurately as it seems to just get triggered when I push a lot of requests at the same time or in a row.

The function code below is what my function looks like:

```
function getPage(){
      var options = {
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/",
        headers: { 'User-agent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20110506 Firefox/4.0.1'
};
      request(options, function(err, resp, body) {

                if (err){
                    throw err;
                    return;
                }
                PagesScraped++;
                console.log(PagesScraped);
                return;
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < 600; i++){
  getPage();
};
```

Note: I realize this code gets the same page 600 times asynchronously, but the error is still present if ran enough times... My local code visits multiple thousands of pages on the same website.